# I get Access Update error 3464 Data Type Mismatch

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access

I have a MS Access solution with the following code:

```vb
Private Sub Command1_Click()
  Dim myrs As Recordset
  Dim myPDF, myStmt As String

  'Open a record set with a list of
  ' invoice number to print

  myStmt = " Select distinct respon from  
             users"
  Set myrs = 
      CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(myStmt)
  ' For each invoice print in a .PDF
  Do until myrs.EOF
  
  ' Set the current path of your PDF file 
  ' invoice
  myPDF = "\\Share1\\*" & Format(myrs.Fields("respon"), "00000") & ".PDF"

  ' Open the report with the proper where condition
  
  DoCmd.OpenReport "Printing OT", acViewPreview, ,"respon = " & myrs.Fields("respon").Value

...
...
```

I have 2 tables involved, one in MS Access and another in SQL Server, both with a field named "respon" as text datatype in both tables.

When the "DoCmd.OpenReport" is executed I get the error:

> Access update error 3464 Data Type Mismatch

I don't know why.

Comment: respon data type might be string which requires quotes.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Respon is text data type in both tables (MS Access and SQL Server)

Comment: OK then add quotes.

Answer (score 1):

To expand what I said in my comment, if the respon data type is string (text is string) then you need to add quotes around it:

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "Printing OT", acViewPreview, ,"respon = '" & myrs.Fields("respon").Value & "'"
```